# Stick Open Windows to be visible

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am looking for program compatible with windows xp used for pinned or stick windows for being minimized by any other windows already opened and running

for example i want to make windows media player visible even when i explorer the folders in another window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have program Always on Top, you can [download it here](http://img.labnol.org/di/always-on-top.zip). It works on windows 7 let me know if it works on XP.
Run it then select the window you like to keep on top and press the <kbd>Ctrl></kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut to stick that window in the front.